# Click Once Application

Tags: clickonce, mage

How can i convert a file .dll extension to .deploy extension

I have two solutions for that. But I don't know it is possible. Please can clarify me.

First thing,  I referred some online sources, they referred like just rename the extension.Is this correct solutions for my question.

Second thing, One person told me to use mage.exe tool. With help this tool you can convert it. If it is possible, please share some reference with us.

If you have any other solutions, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the .dll file will converted automatically when you publish the application..
go to Application properties -> publish tab and click on options button

check `Use ".deploy" file extension`

[image]